# django rest framework get vieset by route basename

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

A basic class based view in django gives view name by

```
reslove(reverse("url-name")).func
```

But is there anyway I get viewset name by route basename. When I try `reverse("basename")` I get errors.

Comment: No, there isn't. What do you want to achieve by this? What is your ultimate aim?

Comment: @JPG by knowing viewset I want to check the actions in the viewset according to request methods.